# How to create a Python package with embedded C++ code

Tags: python, c++, pycharm, ctypes, clion

I want to create a Python package (which will be hosted on a local git repository) that will have most of the code written in C++. Basically I am refactoring/rewriting an old C++ project (new project in CLion) and want to include it in a Python package because it will be used in lots of other Python projects (including Flask web services).

So, I then want to `pip install` my package and it should install like any other Python package.

I am developing on OS X and have the IDEs from JetBrains (PyCharm and CLion).

What are the best practices for creating such a Python project and how would the development + deployment steps look like? How should `setup.py` look like for example? Also can I set the projects up so I can debug both my Python code and the C++ code? How should I build the C++ side of the project?

I would prefer to use as little 3rd party tools as possible.

Also any resources you could point me to would also be helpful.

Comment: Here's a C demo I wrote: https://github.com/aaronchall/swigpython